# how to use Spark-submit configuration: jars,packages:in cluster mode?

Tags: mongodb, maven, configuration, cluster-computing, pyspark

When use Spark-submit in cluster mode(yarn-cluster),jars and packages configuration confused me: for jars, i can put them in HDFS, instead of in local directory . But for packages, because they build with Maven, with HDFS,it can't work. my way like below:

```
spark-submit --jars hdfs:///mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar --driver-class-path /home/liac/test/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://192.168.27.234/test.myCollection2?readPreference=primaryPreferred" --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://192.168.27.234/test.myCollection2"  --packages com.mongodb.spark:hdfs:///user/liac/package/jars/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-1.0.0-assembly.jar:1.0.0 --py-files /home/liac/code/diagnose_disease/tool.zip main_disease_tag_spark.py --master yarn-client
```

error occur:

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Provided Maven Coordinates must be in the form 'groupId:artifactId:version'. The coordinate provided is: com.mongodb.spark:hdfs:///user/liac/package/jars/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-1.0.0-assembly.jar:1.0.0
```

Anyone can tell me how to use jars and packages in cluster mode? and what's wrong with my way?

Comment: In your script: `--master yarn-client` ?

Comment: yes, i also try '--master yarn-cluster'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of the `--packages` argument is wrong:

```
--packages com.mongodb.spark:hdfs:///user/liac/package/jars/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-1.0.0-assembly.jar:1.0.0
```

It needs to be in the form of `groupId:artifactId:version` as the output suggests. You cannot use a URL with it.

An example for [using mongoDB with spark](https://spark-packages.org/package/mongodb/mongo-spark) with the built-in repository support:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:1.0.0
```

If you insist on using your own jar you can provide it via `--repositories`. The value of the argument is

> Comma-separated list of remote repositories to search for the Maven coordinates specified in packages.

For example, in your case, it could be

```
--repositories hdfs:///user/liac/package/jars/ --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:1.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! that help me a lot.